# Reducing dll size vc++

Tags: visual-c++, size, reduce

I want reduce the size of my application as much as possible using VisualStudio 8. 
what are the compiler options that are required to be set for this?

Here are the ones the i have set

1.project properties->configuration properties->General->use of MFC
"Use MFC in a Shared DLL"
2.project properties->configuration properties->c/c++->optimization->optimization
"Minimize Size (/O1)"
3.project properties->configuration properties->c/c++->optimization->Favor Size or Speed
"Favor Small Code (/Os)"

Please let me know the other options that can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your compiler options are on the right lines but there are others for compiler and linker.  Take a look at the article [here](http://www.catch22.net/tuts/minexe) which has some other ideas, depending on how much work you want to put into this.

Comment: Thanks Steve the link was extensive, but is there any simple linker or compiler option that i have missed out for reducing size.

Comment: If i have an exe and a number of dependent dlls (MFC) should all of the have the same linker configuration for "project properties->configuration properties->General->use of MFC" or can some be shared dlls and others statically linked, for working in windows environment (suppose the MFC dependencies for all shared components are available in the user's system).

Comment: I don't know for sure.  I imagine mixing (if it works) could increase overall runtme size by including both static and DLL versions of some MFC code.  Why would you want to mix them?

Comment: If i have an exe and a number of dependent dlls (MFC) should all of the have the same linker configuration for "project properties->configuration properties->General->use of MFC" or can some be shared dlls and others statically linked, for working in windows environment (suppose the MFC dependencies for all shared components are available in the user's system).